# Is WebRTC Coming to Android WebView? When?

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I am seeing some contradicting evidence to the question of support of WebRTC in Android's WebView, and I was wondering if anyone might know anything about Google's plans to support WebRTC in the WebView in the future.

On one hand, I have read a post by Paul Irish claiming that WebRTC will be supported on Android WebView, and I also see the same it true by looking at [Chromium SVN](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=revision&revision=253110).

However WebRTC does not actually work on WebView and I found posts saying that [it was eventually left out](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) (no reason given, I can only guess that Google was in a hurry to put the Chromium-based WebView in KitKat and to reduce complication stuff like WebRTC and WebGL were left out).

Does anyone know if Google is planning to add WebRTC support for the Android WebView, and when?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:
On Google I/O 2014, Google revealed that Web View will support WebRTC only on Android "L".

Answer (score 4):

WebRTC is **not** supported in the WebView.

The team would like to enable it (which is why I think that bug exists), but to enable features, they need to be supported across all Android architectures (Mips, Arm, Intel), which I don't believe WebRTC is.

Update: As pointed out below - I/O 2014, we announced support for WebRTC.

Here is a short video on other updates and code on how to get it working on the L Developer Preview.

https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/07/02/webview-in-the-developer-preview-of-l

**Warning**: As this is only a preview release of Android, there may be some changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the supported architectures depend on the implementation of the WebRTC spec, it's just a matter of effort that is needed. Do you happen to know if Google is planning to add WebRTC support in the near future? Is this something that Google right now views as a bug?

Comment: There is this bug for WebRTC to be enabled in the WebView. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316499

That would probably be the best place to track status, star it and you should get updates.

Comment: Thanks again. Will wait to see if anyone else might have any idea about timelines for getting it to work (if there's no answer in reasonable time I will accept yours as the solution).

Comment: @orcaman - "Gaunt Face" works on the project with the engineering team :) there is no public official timeline of when it will happen because WebView is tied to OS updates, but you can see it is actively being worked on!

Comment: when is an option to disable it coming?

Comment: Disable what? This question is 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too old but this is them who wants to implement WebRTC in to previous platform. I have tested it also woks on my kitkat phone

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html

Crosswalk is a web runtime that can be used to replace the stock WebView used by Android or Cordova apps. Crosswalk is based on Google Chromium with Cordova API support and has better HTML5 feature support compared to the default WebView available in Android.

Just replace the Webview with crosswalk which is used in the application.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: can you disable it in crosswalk?